# In Swift 4.0 - Circle doesn't appear when added from code

Tags: swift, gamekit

I am trying to add a circle for a second and then remove it, so the user could see where was the collision point. But from some reason I don't see the circle after I add it - It's a game in SpriteKit.

```
func drawCircleOnCollisionPoint(circleCenter:CGPoint) {
    let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    circle.position = circleCenter
    circle.strokeColor = SKColor.red
    circle.glowWidth = 1.0
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.clear
    circle.zPosition = 50
    self.addChild(circle)
    sleep(1)
    circle.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Never never `sleep`.

Comment: You were right! Thank you it's working now!